# TypeOrm putting double quotes when generating the Crud operations

Tags: oracle, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

Im using **typeorm **with **nestjs **to work with **oracle** database.

1. When I use repository way  to get some data from oracle database I'm getting following error:
   Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

async findAll(): Promise<BRANCHE[]> {
let brancheListe: BRANCHE[] = null;

```
try {
  brancheListe = await this.brancheRepository.find();
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}

return brancheListe;
```

}

2. When I look at the generated select statement, it has double quotes, which i believe is the case    that oracle can't find the table or view.

query: SELECT "Branche"."ID" AS "Branche_ID", "Branche"."BRANCHE" AS "Branche_BRANCHE", "Branche"."BRACHE_NAVN" AS "Branche_BRACHE_NAVN", "Branche"."TS" AS "Branche_TS" FROM "branche" "Branche" WHERE branche.id < :1 -- PARAMETERS: [10]
query failed: SELECT "Branche"."ID" AS "Branche_ID", "Branche"."BRANCHE" AS "Branche_BRANCHE", "Branche"."BRACHE_NAVN" AS "Branche_BRACHE_NAVN", "Branche"."TS" AS "Branche_TS" FROM "branche" "Branche" WHERE branche.id < :1 -- PARAMETERS: [10]
error: Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

3. If I use the repository way with query then its works fine

async findAll(): Promise<BRANCHE[]> {
let brancheListe: BRANCHE[] = null;

```
try {
  brancheListe = await this.brancheRepository.query(
    'SELECT * FROM BRANCHE',
  );
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
return brancheListe;
```

}

4. Do anybody know how i force the TypeOrm not to use doube quotes?
   is ther any options im missing?

I just wanna know how can stop TypeORM to put double quoutes "" for the generated sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow TypeORM to use the double quotes. Instead, fix your entity so that the double quoted identifiers in the queries have the correct case (upper-case).

If you have:

```nodejs
@Entity()
export class Branche {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    ID: number

    @Column()
    BRANCHE: string

    @Column()
    BRACHE_NAVN: string

    @Column()
    TS: string
}
```

You can try either:

```nodejs
@Entity()
export class BRANCHE {
...
```

or, specify the table name with the [`Entity` decorator](https://typeorm.io/decorator-reference#entity):

```nodejs
@Entity("BRANCHE")
export class Branche {
...
```

or:

```nodejs
@Entity({name: "BRANCHE"})
export class Branche {
...
```

Comment: Hi MT0,

Thanks for the the real good examples.

Following worked for me
@Entity()
export class BRANCHE {
...@   
                                                                                                             
and 

@Entity("BRANCHE")
export class Branche {

Thanks for saving me for frustrating day again :)

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes tells Oracle that the object name is case-sensitive and exactly as spelled, and can include special characters. Otherwise, Oracle will treat all object names as UPPER_CASE with underscores, # and $ but no other characters (like spaces) permitted.

So, if you use `" "` you  must provide the correct case. That's probably upper case, so convert your schema, column and table names to all caps and see if that works. Most likely it's your table name.. instead of `from "Branch"` make it say `from "BRANCHE"`

Comment: Hi Paul.                                                  
Im not able to change the oracle database as I only have read access.                                                      

I will try your suggestion to change table/entity to uppercase and column names. I will let you know the result. Hopefully you are right and I will be a happy man 

Comment: I'm not suggesting you alter anything in the database. You need to put your object names in uppercase in your client code.

Comment: Hi Paul,

It helped from "Branch" make it say from "BRANCHE" - Thanks